# Ensure uniqueness of data before creating object?

Tags: c++

I have a file full of data that I need to operate on. Each line of this file contains floating point numbers (represented as strings of course) like this:

x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 x3 y3 z3 r1 g1 b1 r2 g2 b2 r3 g3 b3

each line represents 3 different objects that I need to create, like:
`Foo foo1(x1,y1,z1,r1,g1,b1);`
`Foo foo2(x2,y2,z2,r2,g2,b2);`
`Foo foo3(x3,y3,z3,r3,g3,b3);`

the twist is that:

1. I want to ONLY create objects if they haven't been created yet. if I've already made a `Foo` with those exact same 6 floats, instead of creating a new `Foo` I want to just retrieve that object I already made.
2. The data in the file is unreliably delimited -- there could be any number of spaces or tabs between the different numbers.

Before I realized this issue with the spacing, I was splitting each line I read from the file into strings, concatenating the strings that represented each foo, and then using a `std::map<std::string,int>` to test for uniqueness, where the int returned by the map represented an index into a `std::vector<Foo*>` that I was pushing pointers to each `Foo` I was creating into. This fails when the spacing isn't consistent.

all I can think of right now is doing something like:
http://codepad.org/hLhFzhPh (for example) but that seems completely screwy. I also tried making a struct of 6 floating point values, overloading `operator>>` to read from a stringstream into it, and then making a `map<weirdstruct,int>` but I didn't really know how to overload `operator<` to make this work.

Anyway, this seems like it should be easy and I just don't have a clue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

1: Use an `std::set<Foo>` to record what you've already constructed. The `std::map` + `std::vector` solution is both unreliable and, when fixed, overkill.

2: The following skips over any leading spaces in the input:

```
double x;
std::cin >> x;
```

and similar for any `std::istream`.

Comment: wouldn't this require constructing a `Foo`, checking to see if it is in the set, then throwing it away if it is? It seems like a pretty good solution because in this case the `Foo` ctor is very lightweight -- but how would you solve the problem if constructing a `Foo` was expensive, and we wanted to pre-emptively avoid the call to `Foo(float,float,float,float,float,float)`?

Comment: @Alexander: if your constructor becomes too heavy, introduce a `struct Bar` with constructor `Bar::Bar(float,float,float,float,float,float)` and construct `Foo` from `Bar const &` instead of from six floats.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to have to unaccept this answer. After trying to implement it, I don't think it is going to work, because the identity of my foo objects is important -- if I try to use the Foo that I get out of the `std::set<Foo>`, I'm actually getting a copy constructed Foo, which is identical to the case I'm trying to prevent! this is why originally wanted to use a map<std::string,int> where int indexed into a std::vector<Foo*> (though now that I think of it, seems like I could just use a std::map<std::string,Foo*>)

Comment: @Alexander: `std::string` is unreliable because (as Jerry noted) every float has myriad string representations. If saving on constructors is such a great concern, then why not an `std::set<Bar>`? That's still more compact than your option.

Comment: Because I don't just need to check if a given `Foo` exists before I make it -- I also need to be able to retrieve identically that `Foo` in the case if it does already exist. A `std::map<Bar, Foo*>` would probably be best, but I just ended up doing going from input-> string -> string stream -> floats -> stringstream -> string to normalize my string representation of the floats, and then used a `std::map<std::string,Foo*>`... probably not ideal but it got the job done. I'll probably refactor it later today. That also raises the sticky issue of imposing an `operator<` onto a struct of 6 floats

Comment: @Alexander: if you implement `Bar` using a `float[6]`, then your `operator<` reduces to `std::lexicographical_compare`. http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lexicographical_compare.html

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd convert the inputs to real floating point before comparing. With floating point numbers, differences in the string representation don't necessarily signify differences in the actual value. Just for example, `12345` is equal to `1.2345e4`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if you just want a quick solution.

```
std::stringstream sIn(theline);
std::stringstream sOut;

std::string temp;

while (sIn >> temp) sOut << temp << " ";

std::string fixedline = sOut.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is finding an exact match since you are using floating point numbers.

I suggest adding an `operator==(x,y,z,r,g,b)` to `Foo`.  Place all your `Foo` objects into a container and compare them using the `operator==()`, to see if a `Foo` object has already been created.

An alternative method is to factor out the `<x,y,z,r,g,b>` into a parent structure.  Create a container of these.  When you create a `Foo` object, put an instance into the container.  You can search the container before you create the *next* `Foo` instance.

I also suggest transposing the data file so that each line contains only one *vector* of x,y,z,r,g,b.  Sort the file.  Remove duplicates before giving it to your program.  Use applications outside of your program to do this (preferred).  Cygwin and Linux have some nice utilities for sorting and removing duplicates.

### Edit1: Example 3D point with input operator (untested)

```
ifndef POINT3D_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class Point3d
{
public:
    Point3d(double x = 0.0, double y = 0.0, double z = 0.0)
        : m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z)
        { ; }
    Point3d(const Point3d& p3d)
        : m_x(p3d.m_x), m_y(p3d.m_y), m_z(p3d.m_z)
        { ; }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, Point3d& p3d);

    bool operator==(const Point3d& p) const
        {
            return (std::fabs(m_x - p.m_x) < 5.0E-5)
                && (std::fabs(m_y - p.m_y) < 5.0E-5)
                && (std::fabs(m_z - p.m_z) < 5.0E-5);
        }

private:
    double m_x;
    double m_y;
    double m_z;
};

inline std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& inp, Point3d& p)
{
    inp >> p.m_x;
    inp >> p.m_y;
    inp >> p.m_z;
    return inp;
}

#endif // POINT3D_HPP

class Foo
: public Point3d
{
public:
    Foo(double x, double y, double z,
        double r, double g, double b)
    : Point3d(x, y, z),
      m_r(r), m_g(g), m_b(b)
    { ; }

    Foo(const Point3d& p3d,
        double r, double g, double b)
    : Point3d(p3d),
      m_r(r), m_g(g), m_b(b)
    { ; }

    double m_r, m_g, m_b;
};
```

Reading of the data file becomes something like this:

```
  std::ifstream data_file("data.bin");
  Point3d p1;
  Point3d p2;
  Point3d p3;
  // Input the first 3 points on the line.
  data_file >> p1;
  data_file >> p2;
  data_file >> p3;
  // Or:  data_file >> p1 >> p2 >> p3

  // Before creating a Foo:
  std::vector<Point3d> existing_points;
  std::vector<Point3d>::const_iterator iter;
  bool is_duplicate = false;
  for (iter = existing_points.begin();
       iter != existing_points.end();
       ++iter)
  {
      if (*iter == p1)
      {
         is_duplicate = true;
         break;
      }
  }
  if (! is_duplicate)
  {
     existing_points.push_back(p1);
     // Create a new Foo
  }
```

The color values can be treated in a very similar fashion (so similar, you could just change member names and class names).

Comment: "I also suggest transposing the data file so that each line contains only one vector of x,y,z,r,g,b." this would be nice, but would break the specification :(